# How do you merge arrays with same id using Spark DataFrames?

Tags: java, sql, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

My table looks like this

```
+-------+--------------------+
|id     |                  c1|
+-------+--------------------+
|      1|ArrayBuffer(a,b)    |
|      1|ArrayBuffer(c  )    |
|      2|ArrayBuffer(d  )    |
|      2|ArrayBuffer(e,f)    |
|      2|ArrayBuffer(g  )    |
|      3|ArrayBuffer(h  )    |
+-------+--------------------+
```

I want to the output to look like this

```
+-------+--------------------+
|id     |                  c1|
+-------+--------------------+
|      1|ArrayBuffer(a,b,c)  |
|      2|ArrayBuffer(c,d,e,f,g)
|      3|ArrayBuffer(h  )    |
+-------+--------------------+
```

Here's what I was thinking

SQLQuery = "SELECT table.id, join(table.c1) FROM table GROUP BY table.id

```
 sqlContext.udf().register("join",
               new UDF1<ArrayBuffer, ArrayBuffer>() {
                   @Override
                   public ArrayBuffer call(ArrayBuffer idArray) {

                      // how do I join them?

                       return idArray;

                   }
              }, DataTypes.StringType);
```

Comment: Hmm.. is it essential that the operation happens on a DataFrame? If you get the rdd instead, it can be done with a simple reduceByKey: `df.rdd.map{case(id: Int, c1: ArrayBuffer[String]) => (id,c1)}.reduceByKey(_++_)`

Comment: I ended up doing it this way, I just wanted a clean way to query it.